# How to send id instead of whole object in Spring MVC??? (Hibernate/Spring-Data-JPA)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have one Question entity in my Spring project, which is being sent as a response. Question entity has **@ManyToOne** relationship with **User** entity.

**Question class**

```
@Entity
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int questionId;
    
    @Column
    private String question;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private List<Answer> answerList;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<Answer> getAnswerList() {
        return answerList;
    }

    public void setAnswerList(List<Answer> answerList) {
        this.answerList = answerList;
    }

    public int getQuestionId() {
        return questionId;
    }

    public void setQuestionId(int questionId) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
    
}
```

**User class**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userId;
    
    private String userName;
    

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

}
```

I am sending a response in a JSON format. Below is the example of my response for a single question.

```
{
"questionId": 1,
"question": "What is java?",
"user": {
"userId": 1,
"userName": "JeffHardy"
},
"answerList": [],
}
```

Just notice the **user** object in JSON. Whole user object is being sent as a response. I just want to return **userId** instead of **user** object. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the fields with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "fieldName" })` annotation on class level.
for example:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "userName" })
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userId;
    
    private String userName;
    

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

}
```

But I suggest to create customized classes for response jsons.